# Issue with HTML Label (Javascript)

Tags: jquery, html

I use the following code and I have some issues with the HTML outcome seen on the console:

HTML Code I would like to generate:

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">

  <tbody id="tabledata">
  <tr>
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
  <td>250</td>
  <td>$2.90</td>
</tr>

<script>
    createTable();
    </script>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

createTable appends the following:

```
$('#tabledata').append("<tr><td class=\"mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric\">" + 
    Produkt + "</td><td>"+ Anzahl +"</td><td>"+ Datum +"</td></tr>");
```

The issues is that the output of createtable produces different table rows - and I do not know why?!

```
<tr>
     <td>
          <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select mdl-js-ripple-effect--ignore-events is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialCheckbox,MaterialRipple">
                <input type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__focus-helper"></span>
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__box-outline">
                      <span class="mdl-checkbox__tick-outline"></span>
                </span>
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__ripple-container mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-ripple--center" data-upgraded=",MaterialRipple">
                     <span class="mdl-ripple"></span>
                </span>
           </label>
      </td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Eis</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>25.8.2017 22:37</td>
</tr>
```

versus:

```
<tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Eis</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>25.8.2017 22:37</td>
</tr>
```

Do you know why?

Comment: In future... please put your code on multiple lines as putting that much on a single line makes it harder to figure out.

Comment: Variable `Produkt` probably contains HTML string inside it.

Comment: maybe it is because your screen is too small to display the whole content in that row, or you set the table with a fixed css size.

Comment: Are you using any plugin ?!

Comment: thanks for the hints - next time I will do better :-) Produkt does not contain any html code it is a simple string. I am not using any plug in. The rows are not too long.

Comment: I just saw that this way to create checkboxes is depreciated. .... [link](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations) the current code works.